# Its correct to assume the Sum Set using "for all" quantifier in place of existential quantifier?

Tags: set-theory

From ZFC Axiom of union we have: $$(\forall x)(\exists y)(\forall u)(u \in y \Leftrightarrow (\exists v)(u \in v \land v \in x))$$
My interpretation of this is that  for any set $x$ its guarantee a set $y$ exists containing, every member of member of x. and im trying to solve an exercise which its to prove that some set $z$ is transitive if, and only if sum set of $z$ is a subset of $z$, i started assuming that sum set of $z$ is a subset of z:
$$\bigcup z \subseteq z$$
From this i changed the expression to this:
$$\bigcup z \subseteq z \Leftrightarrow (\forall u)(u \in \bigcup z \Rightarrow u \in z)$$
Now come my doubt, saying $u$ belongs to Sum set of $x$, can be changed to something like
$$(\forall u)(\forall v)((u \in v \land v \in z) \Rightarrow u \in z)$$
I believe it have something wrong because $(\Rightarrow)$ side of the proof will terminate here if its correct. I did i right? if this is not correct let me know how a proof for this should be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you’re trying to prove is what I normally take as the definition of $z$ being transitive, so I’m assuming that your definition is that $z$ is transitive if $x\in y\in z$ implies that $x\in z$. I would use fewer symbols and more words:

> Assume that $\bigcup z\subseteq z$, and suppose that $u\in v\in z$. Then by definition $u\in\bigcup z$, so $u\in z$, and $z$ is therefore transitive.

That really is all that needs to be said unless you’re specifically being asked for a much more formal argument.

**Added:** For the opposite implication suppose that $z$ is transitive, and let $x\in\bigcup z$. Then by definition there is some $u\in z$ such that $x\in u$, and transitivity of $z$ then implies that $x\in z$. Since $x$ was an arbitrary element of $\bigcup z$, it follows that $\bigcup z\subseteq z$.

Here again I think that it’s better to avoid getting bogged down in a lot of symbols and to use words to make the flow of logic clear.

Comment: You assumed correct on the definition, and its now more clear to me, and the exercise stated this as an equivalence, so its needed to prove that "if z is transitive then sum set of z is a subset of z" too, right?

Comment: @PauloHenriqueL.Amorim: Yes, that’s right. Do you want me to add something about that direction?

Comment: Ir will be nice, and let me ask, its wrong to ask other questions in comments or its allowed? i was doing the next exercise which its prove empty set as transitive. and it seems to very easy to be correct, i just assumed it transitive because the implication is trivially true.

Comment: @Paulo: Okay, I’ll add something in a few minutes. You’re right that it’s pretty trivial that the empty set is transitive: the English expression is that the statement $x\in y\in\varnothing\to x\in\varnothing$ is *vacuously true*, because $x\in y\in\varnothing$ is always false, so the implication really doesn’t say anything in this case.